# Number of input channels for convolutional network

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm following the "Deep MNIST for Experts" tutorial for TensorFlow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/

The second convolutional layer has the shape [5, 5, 32, 64]; that is, it has 32 inputs whereas the first convolutional layer had 1 input (that input being I understand the grayscale values of the original image).

What does it mean that the second convolutional layer has 32 input channels? Does it mean the 64 filters that are learned in the second layer will all be applied (shifted around) to a "virtual" image having 32 points per pixel (this "virtual" image being composed of the original image to which each filter learned in the first step has been applied)? How do you apply a 2D 5x5 filter to an image having 32 points/values per pixel if what I said previously is correct?

Comment: How ever I understand your question , I don't think SO is the best place for such questions, try Data Science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first convolution layer has the following weights:

```
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
```

Here `5x5` is the patch size `1` is the number of input channels and `32` is the number of output channels. So after the first convolution the output has 32 channels, hence the shape of the weight matrix for second convolution layer has `32` input channels.

Comment: So you mean just like a color image has three channels (RGB), the one after the first convolution has 32? How do we multiply a 5x5 filter matrix with a 5x5 portion of an image having 32 channels? (Or more simply put with an image having more than one channel).

Comment: "So you mean just like a color image has three channels (RGB), the one after the first convolution has 32?" Exactly.
"How do we multiply a 5x5 filter matrix with a 5x5 portion of an image having 32 channels?" Imagine you have a 5x5x32 filter. You multiply this with the `corresponding` patch of the image and sum up all the values to get a scalar. Here your weight matrix has dimensions [5, 5, 32, 64] which means there are 64 such filters for each patch of the image which will give you 64 scalars. If you perform this over the entire image you get a new image with 64 channels. Hope that clarifies

Comment: @TheMyth Just to be precise, we would get 64 channels per patch rather than per image right ? I assume convolution is done by taking  patches centred on each input pixel, hence the number of  output neurons for this layer will be image size * image size * 64 ?